# Having difficulty using regex to replace strings from Pandas column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

So, I've learning to deal with missing values in Pandas dataframes, and I'm now trying to use `regex` to remove some missing values in a column of numbers in string format. This is a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgol4.png) of my data (to avoid posting a huge screenshot).

I'd normally use `.dropna` to deal with numeric `NaN`'s, but since the missing value is a row which is just a period (`'.'`) in the string Gold column, that doesn't work and I can't event convert the column to float, either, because of that.

After some research, this regex method,

```
data5['Gold'].replace(r'\D',np.nan,regex=True,inplace=True)
```

to replace all values that are not digits, `'\D'`, should work, but every value gets null'd in the process, and I can't seem to figure out why. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: After a recommendation, I've tried copy-pasting a subset of my troublesome data using `.to_dict`, in an effort to show what is going on.

```
Date           APPLE     IBM        Gold     VIX
67 2004-04-08  1.331187  69.479301  422.000  16.26
68 2004-04-12  1.355847  69.941895        .  15.28
69 2004-04-13  1.302174  69.419609  417.450  17.26
70 2004-04-14  1.288152  69.912048  405.750  15.62
```

Comment: `df['Gold'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Gold'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)`

Comment: This did it for me, thanks a lot. After having run `to_numeric` while coercing the errors, I separately tried running `fillna(0)`, but it didn't work because I forgot most pandas operations aren't in place.

However, is there any reason why the regex command wouldn't work in my situation?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a column of mixed strings and floats, which was interfering with the replacement (mixed dtypes are just NaN'd).

Comment: How would I get around this error, then? Do you have any ideas? It seems important to be able to run basic `regex` methods on data, even if it's mixed.

Comment: You'll want to do `data5['Gold'] = data5['Gold'].astype(str)` first.